# Xcode 5 - Show edited files?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is anyone else noticing this? When I edit a file in Xcode 5, it does not (like in Xcode 4) darken the icon for the file. This would be visible at the title bar and also in the file navigator.

Looked around in Preferences but didn't find anything.

Also, I thought maybe it meant that any time you edited a file it would auto-write the file, but it does not appear to do this either.

Comment: In Xcode 4 the darkened icon meant that the file has some unsaved changes. In Xcode 5 all files are saved on the fly (whenever you type something). That's why they are not darkened anymore ;)

Comment: @HAS Hmm. okay maybe then my testing I did wasn't very thorough. I guess I'll worry about it when I run into the situation where I lose work which should hopefully never happen. This is a welcome change, I guess.

Comment: Yes it is! I ran the mavericks beta from the beginning on and had some crashes and never lost a single letter of my code. I have to admit I didn't test it and I don't have a Mac here right know but my experience with Xcode tells me that those days are gone ;)

Comment: Cool. make it an answer, it's a much more correct answer than the posted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience with Xcode 5 is that it automatically saves all your files for you. I can't comment on how often the files are actually written to disk but using the Mavericks Beta since day 1 and having had some crashes I never lost a line of code (not even a letter).

So there doesn't need to be darkened file icon anymore since no file will ever have pending changes that need to be written to to disk.

Comment: I'll note that during my testing Xcode 5 appears to reliably write the file only at certain events such as losing Xcode application focus. This is sort of obviously needed because it cannot afford to write to disk on every keypress. I am using an Xcode plugin and it occasionally crashes Xcode. When this happens the last few bits I typed are actually lost. This isn't any worse than with Xcode 4.6 though, as that would not save until you told it to. Still, it would be even nicer if there was some visual feedback that the file is actually really saved.

Comment: Also, it's unreasonable to expect an editor to be completely resilient against crashing (because it is not supposed to crash). I would imagine that the next frontier would be setting up a daemon process that manages and mirrors changes which will not be susceptible to the main program crashing. No editor I know of provides this feature.

Comment: Nice observations! I didn't expect it either to save after every key press but I actually thought of some kind of daemon process too which handles all this. This would really be a nice feature! I think it wouldn't cost a lot of RAM, it just needed be a small buffer. We could make a feature request via bugreporter!

Comment: @StevenLu I just discovered that Xcode five point 1 DP 2 shows the edited files just like Xcode < 5 did! :)

Comment: Oh that's pretty sweet! Looking forward to making that switch. I guess they finally realized what a silly move removing file-saving was. This is an IDE folks, we don't need this level of hand-holding.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is set up to use version control, the Project Navigator will display an 'M' to the right of modified files and an 'A' for new files. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No because this works the same as Xcode 4... It is an orthogonal feature because the `A` and `M` markers indicate the git repository edited status. I'm talking about editing it before saving where Xcode will tell me (like any other half decent editor of any sort) that the changes are still in RAM and not written to disk yet. There's no way git knows to mark `M` if the file isn't written...